# Disable cursor in TextCtrl - wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have code as follows

log = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(300,100),
                          style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL|wx.TE_DONTWRAP)

I'm writing logs into this box by redirecting stdout.
How do I make the cursor dissappear for the TextCtrl because it appends logs based on the position of the cursor right now. I dont want to give the user the privilage to place the cursor at a particular spot in the box basically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ummmm

```
log.Enable(False)
```

?

I think ...

or if you feel awesome you could also do

```
log.Disable()
```

Comment: ehhh yeah ... actually thats one of the few things that bother me about wx ... I hate that the add functions that accept params for T/F and then also have the inverse function that also accepts a parameter of T/F ... so I just always use the affirmative method when I have the option between the two (but yes you are unsurprisingly absolutely correct...) @sarathjoseph you should read MikeDriscoll's blog about wx it is very good .... most of what I know of wx came from his blog

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why they did that. I bet you could catch EVT_TEXT too and just call the SetInsertionPointEnd() method...although I'm not sure if the widget would insert the text the moment the handler is called or after you've set the insertion point.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this myself. I resolved it while retaining the ability to highlight entries and use the scrollbar by defining an internal print function in my UI subclass.

```
import wx,sys

class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self,wxTextCtrl):
        self.out=wxTextCtrl
    def write(self,string):
        self.out.WriteText(string)

class SomeGUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        super(SomeGUI,self).__init__(parent,title=title)

        self.mainsizer=wx.GridBagSizer(2,2)
        self.textout=wx.TextCtrl(self,size=(-1,80), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.textout,(0,0),span=wx.GBSpan(1,3),flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.redir=RedirectText(self.textout)
        sys.stdout=self.redir

        self.buttons=[wx.Button(self, label=val) for val in ['Bob Dole', 'Batman', 'Pet Rock']]
        for i,v in enumerate(self.buttons):
            self.mainsizer.Add(v,(1,i),flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.BobDole,self.buttons[0])
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.Batman,self.buttons[1])
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.Rock,self.buttons[2])

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.mainsizer)
        self.Show()

    def iprint(self,string): #iprint because "internal print", not because Apple
        self.textout.SetInsertionPointEnd()
        print(string)

    def BobDole(self,e):
        self.iprint('Bob Dole!')

    def Batman(self,e):
        self.iprint('The hero we deserve.')

    def Rock(self,e):
        self.iprint('It looks happy...')

def main():
    app=wx.App()
    app.locale=wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
    somegui=SomeGUI(None, title='It prints text and stuff')
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Technically speaking, I'd imagine the running time is marginally slower than just disabling the wx.TextCtrl, but I can't see that realistically becoming an issue.

Comment: This is the correct answer here.

Answer (score 1):

But if you use `log.Disable`, the scrollbar won't work

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
self.log.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS,self.onfocus)

def onfocus(self,e):
    self.log.SetInsertionPointEnd()
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows users you can call

```
wx.CallAfter(self.your_text_ctrl.HideNativeCaret)
```

You'll have to call it anytime you update the text